# Unity specular in shadow

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics

Specular, not in shadow

[image]

specular, in shadw

[image]

first of all, I'm not good at english.

there is a problem on realtime lighting. on this scene of the photo, there is only a directional light.
I think less or almost no specular on shadow in this environment.

Am I overly sensitive?

If not, plz let me know how can I solve this problem!

Comment: If your question is if there should be specular light in the shadow, then the answer is no.

Comment: no, i want to erase that specular.

Comment: The answer isn't a hard no, you can have specular reflections in a shadow, but not from the direct light from the light source that is casting the shadow.

Answer (score 0):

https://forum.unity.com/threads/specular-on-shdow.519449/

here is the solution!
i hope someone get help from this post :)

====Becuase of some advices. I add some description.====

I solved this problem.

this problem is because of the shadow's strength. I could find this option in directional light i placed and change it from 0.8 to 1.
and this is perfectly solved.

[problem is solved.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBok2.png)

Comment: Please avoid cross posts on several sites next time.